# Using the modulo operator with integers

Tags: modulo

I'm trying to work out how the modulo operation `1 % 32` is equal to `1`, and `2 % 32` is equal to `2`, and so on and so forth.

I have this code:

```
 uint8_t value;

  for (uint16_t i = 0; i < 64; i++) {

    value = (i % 32);

    Serial.println(value);
  }
```

I get a result of:

> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31

I can see the logic when `i` is equal to `0`, or `i` is equal to `32`.  For instance, if we take the remainder of the latter: `32 / 32` we get `0`.  But, for all the numbers within the range of `1` to `31`, I can't seem to derive the same answer as the program.  For example, if I divide the integers `1` by `32` in order to obtain the remainder, I just get `0`.  This is the same for `2, 3, 4, 5, 6, n,..`

There must be something I'm missing here.

Comment: Do long division - what is the remainder if you try to divide 1 by 32 (you've already stated that the result is 0 but we want the remainder). If you can't seem to get started try dividing 33 by 32 then see how you come up with a remainder. Then do it again for 1 divide by 32. You'll see that the method by which we extract the remainder is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of the [modulo operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) is the remainder:

```
0 divided by 32 equals 0 with a remainder of 0
1 divided by 32 equals 0 with a remainder of 1
2 divided by 32 equals 0 with a remainder of 2
3 divided by 32 equals 0 with a remainder of 3
4 divided by 32 equals 0 with a remainder of 4
5 divided by 32 equals 0 with a remainder of 5

...

29 divided by 32 equals 0 with a remainder of 29
30 divided by 32 equals 0 with a remainder of 30
31 divided by 32 equals 0 with a remainder of 31
32 divided by 32 equals 1 with a remainder of 0
33 divided by 32 equals 1 with a remainder of 1
34 divided by 32 equals 1 with a remainder of 2
35 divided by 32 equals 1 with a remainder of 3
36 divided by 32 equals 1 with a remainder of 4
37 divided by 32 equals 1 with a remainder of 5
38 divided by 32 equals 1 with a remainder of 6
39 divided by 32 equals 1 with a remainder of 7
...
```

So the results you see are what you should expect. Consider `2 % 32`. "2 divided by 32 equals 0 with a **remainder of 2**". So `2 % 32 == 2`.

Comment: Ah, I think I get the concept now.  So because `32` is not divisible by `1` in integer terms, the `1` literally gets left to one side.  So, lets say I have this `2 % 40`, the answer would be `2` because its left over from a `0` outcome?